# Converting java.time.LocalTime to java.sql.Time

Tags: java, java-time, localtime, sql-timestamp

I am currently getting an `IllegalArgumentException` thrown at these lines of code:

```
Time timeIn = Time.valueOf( res.getCheckInTime().toString());
Time timeOut = Time.valueOf( res.getCheckOutTime().toString());
```

Both arguments are `LocalTime` storing the local time such as `11:05`:

- `res.getCheckInTime()`
- `res.getCheckOutTime()`

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: can you share what res.getCheckInTime().toString() prints out?

Comment: 11:05 in string format

Comment: well as already mentioned - you are probably hitting this else snippet - https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/Time.java#L108

Comment: From JavaDoc the instance itself stores nanosecond precision, but [`LocalTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--) may __omit zeros for seconds__ ("format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero"). So it may not satisfy `Time.valueOf` requirements.

Comment: By the way, `java.sql.Time` is part of the terribly flawed date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those classes, including `Time`, were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. If your methods are already using `java.time.LocalTime`, you should generally have no reason to convert to `Time`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to use `res.getCheckInTime().toString()`? Couldn't use the `Time.valueOf(LocalTime s)` method?

See the following example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     LocalTime checkInTime = LocalTime.now();
     LocalTime checkOutTime = LocalTime.now().plusHours(12);

     Time timeIn = Time.valueOf(checkInTime);
     Time timeOut = Time.valueOf(checkOutTime);

     System.out.println("timeIn => " + timeIn);
     System.out.println("timeOut => " + timeOut);
 }
```

---

To convert a `java.time.LocalTime` object to `java.sql.Time`:

```
Time t = Time.valueOf( myLocalTime ) ;
```

To go the other direction, from legacy class `java.sql.Time` to modern class `java.time.LocalTime`:

```
LocalTime lt = t.toLocalTime() ;
```

No strings involved.

Comment: @Basil your addition illustrates a helpful reversal. Recognized a subtle detail: Why did you attribute the `java.sqlTime` as_legacy class_.

Comment: @hc_dev Because Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on those classes with the unanimous adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). The *java.time* classes replace entirely the functionality of the legacy date-time classes. No need to ever use Time, Timestamp, Date, Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** use the safe & concise `Time.valueOf(LocalTime)` as [suggested by Samuel Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70524001/5730279), e.g. `Time.valueOf( res.getCheckInTime() )`.

### Pitfalls when using String-based conversion

The String-variant has 2 pitfalls:

1. `LocalTime.toString()` produces variable output-formats that may cause given `IllegalArgumentException` when used with `Time.valueOf(String)` - two implied assumptions: (a) non-deterministic output causes (b) message-less, thus not very helpful,  exception that let's the user guess which value was passed as argument and why it was illegal.
2. Also the JavaDoc for `Time.valueOf(String)` as [quoted by Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523594/5730279) is misleading. In [current implementation (OpenJDK)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/Time.java#L103) you can pass any other integer-sequence separated by 2 colons, like `-33:9999:88`. Although not a valid ISO-time in format `HH:mm:ss`, it is apparently interpreted as time-value and may lead to serious side-effects! Did you expect `"13:40:28" == Time.valueOf("-33:9999:88")` as result ?

#### `time.LocalTime` has non-deterministic `toString` format

Don't use `LocalTime.toString()` because it's output format is *non-deterministic* and **may vary in precision**, worst-case omitting seconds! It tries to reduce the output to significant parts, minimum format is "HH:mm" as in JavaDoc summary.

For reliable and SQL-compliant String-format use `LocalTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)`. It may always produce format like `HH:mm:ss` as required by `java.sql.Time`.

#### `java.sql.Time` can convert `LocalTime` directly

It should work when passing the argument to factory-method [`java.sql.Time.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-):

- either as ISO-formatted time [`String("11:05:00")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) (up to seconds!). ⚠️ Warning: Potential side-effects if passed String contains invalid ISO-time, e.g. `"99:123:88"` or even `"0:-1:-3"` (see example below).
- or directly as [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). ✔️ Recommended as safest.

#### Solution: illustrates argument variants & side-effects

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Reservation res = new Reservation("11:05", "18:05");
        System.out.println(res);

        System.out.printf("toString returns '11:05:00' as expected? %s\n", "11:05:00".equals(res.getCheckInTime()));
        String isoTimeFormat = res.getCheckOutTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
        System.out.printf("explicit format() returns '%s' as expected by SQL? %s\n", isoTimeFormat, "18:05:00".equals(isoTimeFormat));
        
        Time timeIn = Time.valueOf(res.getCheckInTime()); // recommended argument type
        Time timeOut = Time.valueOf(res.getCheckOutTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
        Time timeTest = Time.valueOf("33:99:88"); // dangerous fun-fact

        System.out.println("sql.Time in: " + timeIn + " , out: " + timeOut);
    }

    static class Reservation {
        LocalTime checkIn;
        LocalTime checkOut;

        public Reservation(String in, String out) {
            this.checkIn = LocalTime.parse(in);
            this.checkOut = LocalTime.parse(out);
        }

        public LocalTime getCheckInTime() {
            return checkIn;
        }

        public LocalTime getCheckOutTime() {
            return checkOut;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Reservation {checkIn: %s, checkOut: %s}", getCheckInTime(), getCheckOutTime());
        }
    }
```

Try runnable [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/nE362a).

See also:

- Dariawan tutorial: [java.sql.Time Examples](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/java/java-sql-time-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc:

> ```
> public static Time valueOf​(String s)
> ```
>
> Converts a string in JDBC time escape format to a Time value.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     s - time in format "hh:mm:ss"
> Returns:
>     a corresponding Time object
> ```

The only accepted format is `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: so I tried this too...  Time timeIn = Time.valueOf( res.getCheckInTime().toString() + ":00"); and it still threw the exception

Comment: @Fred - can you write a reproducible test case in which you pass the string literal "11:05:00" to Time.valueOf() and see if you still get the same exception? If yes - try to attach a debugger to see the exact place in Time's class source code where the exception is thrown

Comment: @Fred, Don't use `LocalTime.toString()` because it's output format is __non-deterministic__ and may vary in precision, worst-case omitting seconds! For reliable and SQL-compliant  String-format use [` LocalTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME).